# how to prove if [T]b is diagonal then there is a scalar "a" such that T(v)=av

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

hey i was trying to prove the next proposition:
given T:V->V for every Basis B,  if the matrix [T]B is diagonal, then there is a scalar "a" for every v in V such that T(v)=av

this is what i managed to do so far:

```
assuming [T]B = {{a1, 0 , ...., 0},{0,a2,....,0},.....,{0,0,....,an}}
v={b1,b2,...bn}
[T(v)]B = {{a1, 0 , ...., 0},{0,a2,....,0},.....,{0,0,....,an}}*{b1,b2,...bn} = 
[b1a1,b2a2,....,bnan]
```

and that's where i got stuck.
would appreciate your help.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We want to show that $T$ is some multiple of the identity, i.e. its matrix in some (and hence every) basis is of the form.
$$[T]B=\begin{pmatrix}
a&0&\dots&0\\
0&a&\dots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&\dots&a
\end{pmatrix}.$$
So assume for contradiction that two of the entries on its diagonal are different:
$$[T]B=\begin{pmatrix}
a&0&0&\dots&0\\
0&b&0&\dots&0\\
0&0&*&\dots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\dots&*
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Now find a change of basis (involving only the fist two basis vectors) that makes $T$ non-diagonal.

Comment: thanks! by change of basis you mean multiplying [I]b,c with [T]b and getting [T]c and show it's not necessarily diagonal?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. (By the way, change-of-basis is done by conjugation by the change-of-basis matrix, I don't know if that's what you meant by "multiplication".)

Comment: yup, that's what i meant with [I]b,c it's the change of basis matrix from b to c.

Comment: somehow i don't get it, it looks like in any case, if all the scalars are a or some are different, if you change basis, it might be non-diagonal.